# Avoid rendering partially loaded HTML pages with requirejs

Tags: html, css, requirejs, requirecss

I'm using requirejs together with the [Require-CSS loader plugin by Guy Bedford](https://github.com/guybedford/require-css). Both libraries work fine, but one nuisance I noticed is that the page gets rendered without the css being present yet which looks quite ugly (in particular together with Bootstrap which shows a toggle button in the far left). While this isn't a problem of either of these two libraries, I'd like to avoid it.

Can this be achieved by expediting the css loading (some parameter in requirejs or require-css?) or the rendering be suppressed until at least the css files have been retrieved?

One other solution would be to include the css files as normal references in the html markup, but I really would like to avoid this and stick with the requirejs methods.

Comment: first require css and in callback require related js file.

Comment: One simple solution would be to set `<body style="display:none;">` and then show the body after JS is loaded.

Comment: Sounds like a good and simple idea @Evilzebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to this would be to set `<body style="display:none;">` and use Javascript to set the body visible after the CSS has loaded. This technique is also used for some Angular applications.